# What is the maximum number of partitions with EFI?

Tags: linux, efi

I was wondering what is the maximum number of partition on an GPT-partitionned drive under Linux.

The GPT partition table can contain up to 128 partitions, but the device nodes for `/dev/sda?` (as described [here](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/docs/device-list/devices.txt), block device of major number 8) only allow `/dev/sda1` up to `/dev/sda15`.

**Does that means that there cannot be more that 15 partitions on a drive, even on a GPT-partitionned drive?**

Comment: The size of the field in the GPT header that holds the number of partition entries has a fixed size of 4 bytes, so defacto it can support a maximum value of 2^32. But individual OSs usually place further limits on the max count. The minimum (number of partition entries) seems to be 128, even if you have less partitions on the drive.

Answer (score 5):

Let's read the fine source.

In `block/partitions/efi.c`, the place to set up gpt partitions is [`efi_partition()`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.8.8/block/partitions/efi.c#L617). Here decides the maximum number of partitions:

```
for (i = 0; i < le32_to_cpu(gpt->num_partition_entries) && i < state->limit-1; i++) {
```

`num_partition_entries` comes from gpt header on the disk, so the maximum number is `state->limit - 1`. `state` is the argument of this function, and this function is called from `check_part()`, from `check_partition()` in the same file, and there comes

```
state->limit = disk_max_parts(hd);
```

So the limit is `disk_max_parts()`,

```
static inline int disk_max_parts(struct gendisk *disk)
{
        if (disk->flags & GENHD_FL_EXT_DEVT)
                return DISK_MAX_PARTS;
        return disk->minors;
}
```

So if the disk device has `GENHD_FL_EXT_DEVT /* allow extended devt */` (loop device, generic ATA/ATAPI disk, SCSI disk, MD RAID), the limit is `DISK_MAX_PARTS` (256), otherwise it's [`minors`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.8.8/include/linux/genhd.h#L171).

In conclusion, usually the maximum number Linux kernel supports is 255.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think that's where using UUIDs comes in to play. In that case, you don't address a block device as /dev/{h,s}dXY but rather, by the device's UUID. Certainly in that case, the limit would be supremely beyond excess of 128.

Comment: It is not true, because number defining stored partitions on disk in GPT header is only 32 bit. That mean you can't have more than 2^32 partitions.

Answer (score 2):

No, it means that Linux has a problem.  ☺  [But we knew that already.](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/faq.php#faq-8)

Who told you that the EFI partition table contains *up to* 128 partitions?  That person cannot read specifications.  [As I've said before](https://superuser.com/questions/297243), 128 entries of 128 bytes each is the **minimum** size that is required by the EFI Specification, not *the* size of an EFI partition table, and certainly not the *maximum* size.

(Strictly speaking the minimum, first mentioned in version 1.10 of the EFI Specification, is 16KiB total for all partition entries, but not including the header block.  With the conventional 128 byte entry length, that's a minimum of 128 entries.)