# Make windows unmount a specific partition when hibernating

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot, hibernate, unmount

Could I possibly trick windows in to thinking it's a flash drive? I dual boot, this would be really nice to have.

Comment: ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION for answers below: If you want to share files between both OS, formatting a separate partition as FAT will work.  FAT doesnt recieve hiberfiles from windows. So, you can enable sharing files with read/write for both OS with the a FAT partition. You can always use NTFS as read-only storage in your linux.

Comment: The solution I settled on eventually was formatting the drive as exFAT, especially since Windows 10+ does a pseudo-hibernation instead of shutting down all the way.

Answer (score 2):

You could make Windows un-mount a mount point and then hibernate with a simple batch script:

```
mountvol Path /d
shutdown /h /f /t 0
```

where *Path* is the full path to the mount point.

Once the script is created, make a shortcut to it in the Start menu (assuming you use it) and set a keyboard shortcut so that you can run it with a couple of key-presses.

See more on the [mountvol](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb490934.aspx) and [shutdown](http://www.computerhope.com/shutdown.htm) commands. Note that Windows 8 has [deprecated and hidden hibernate](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2016932/how-to-enable-hibernate-mode-in-windows-8.html), and [you may need to enable and fix it](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/238ec268-a2dc-49ab-8a75-c185710e086a/windows-81-sleephibernate-issues?forum=w8itprohardware).

Comment: Is there a way to make it happen automatically before fastboot?

Comment: See *shutdown* command-line switches. Above. /h is *hibernate*.

Answer (score 2):

@DrMoishe Pippik's answer was almost there, but there was a few things he missed.

To unmount the partition (so you can write to it from another operating system), [you must use `mountvol.exe`'s `/P` tag](http://tuxera.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=30790). This tag `Removes the volume mount point from the specified directory, dismounts the volume, and makes the volume not mountable.` In @DrMoishe Pippik's answer `/D` only `Removes the mount point from the specified directory`, and is why after using his commands, the partition I wanted to unmount was still locked by Windows.

Second of all, you want `mountvol.exe` to run to completion before hibernation is triggered. To do this we use `START /WAIT`.

[image: Shortcut properties showing 'Run as administrator' option]

Lastly, to unmount a partition, you must have Administrator permissions. You can do this, but creating a shortcut of the batch file below, and tick `Advanced > Run as administrator` on the `Shortcut` panel.

**So, this is what the hibernate script should look like:**

```
START /WAIT mountvol.exe <DRIVE LETTER> /P
shutdown /h
```

For hybrid shutdown, you may use:

```
START /WAIT mountvol.exe <DRIVE LETTER> /P
shutdown -hybrid -f -t 00
```

In Windows 8 you can access this from your Start Menu by placing this shortcut in your `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` directory, or globally, `C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`.

[image: Start menu showing hibernate mount/unmount icons.]

---

To remount the drive after you have come out of hibernation, you will need a `Mount` shortcut as well. This will look like:

```
mountvol <DRIVE LETTER> <VOLUME ID>
```

To find the volume ID of your partition, [type `mountvol` into cmd](https://superuser.com/questions/465730/access-to-a-disk-drive-using-volume-id-instead-of-a-drive-letter-in-windows/465741). This shows a list of the partitions in your computer. If you have already unmounted the drive you are wanting to re-mount, it may say `*** NOT MOUNTABLE UNTIL A VOLUME MOUNT POINT IS CREATED ***` underneath it (as shown below).

[image]

Comment: That's a pretty nice answer! I ended up formatting it to exFAT, which I can access from Ubuntu or Windows, and Windows doesn't giver it hiberfiles.