# Access Volume via UID in PowerShell

Tags: audio, powershell, uid

I do have a Server with plenty of volumes where some are mounted in different directories and others have drive letters.
I´m looking for a way to run something like this in Powershell

```
foreach ($element in (Get-Volume).Path) {

Get-childitem -path $element -File}
```

but i haven´t found a way that -path is accepting the volume UID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the `-Path` parameter to `-LiteralPath`:

```
 Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath '\\?\Volume{45908b94-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}\'
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

No luck with this either, but:

Cmd.exe will accept the GUID in a dir command provided the trailing backslash is doubled.

```
C:\> dir \\?\Volume{26a449ef-cba1-4ed4-8b68-0958ea44d71d}\\
```

Explorer will also show the volume when using

```
PS> start "\\?\Volume{53663bce-0000-0000-0000-30b51000000}\"
```

Some links on the issue
[Google search](http://www.google.come/search?q=powershell+access+volume+with+uid)
[Volume GUIDs – Ways To View/Access The Files Within](https://virtuallyaware.wordpress.com/2008/07/23/volume-guids-ways-to-viewaccess-the-files-within/)
[Access to a disk drive using volume ID](https://superuser.com/questions/465730/access-to-a-disk-drive-using-volume-id-instead-of-a-drive-letter-in-windows/465741)

Comment: I know that post already but I don't want to start an explorer but want to work with the ps output in some CSV export.