# Is it safe to remove the driveletter of the physical drive when native-booting from a VHDX in it?

Tags: virtualization, boot-partition, vhdx

I'm trying isolate the physical disks/drives away from the VHDX booted OS. Physicals partitions can either be unmounted(drive letter removed) or the other physical disks themselves disabled.

The final remaining question is whether I can remove the letter from the drive containing the VHDX the system is booting from. The disk management shows the vhdx has been mounted giving access to the virtual partitions. Does that mean the system will break if I remove the drive letter from the physical drive?

Comment: It is indeed [possible](https://superuser.com/questions/465730/access-to-a-disk-drive-using-volume-id-instead-of-a-drive-letter-in-windows) to access a partition without assigning it a drive letter

Comment: Okay it works, thanks. I tried mounting another VHD using the same path (/Device/HarddiskVolume..../...vhdx) but that didn't work. I guess it's just for the boot vhdx then.

Comment: It’s not clear what your trying to achieve by not assigning a drive letter to the volume containing the virtual HDD.

Comment: I wanted to hide the physical drives from 'This-PC', while only having virtual disk drives visible. As for the second VHD that I attempted to attach after having booted into windows, turns out Diskpart/diskmgmt doesn't support using volume-guids. But somehow I was able to mount a vhd using a drive-lettered path and then remove the letter from the physical drive. I was hoping for a way to achieve the same without having to use a letter on a physical drive in the first place. If that makes sense.

Comment: There is a group policy to hide drive letters.  This would make it impossible to view the contents of the drive with File Explorer.

Comment: Okay that's new to me. I have to take a look into that. Thanks.