# Max partition no. on a harddisk

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the maximum number of partitions that can be made on a hard drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/368173/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-partitions-that-can-be-made-on-a-hard-drive)

This question may be repeated.

Can anyone tell how many partitions we can create on a hard disk?
While alphabet no are 26 then how we will assign drive letter for more than 24 partition.

Comment: Thanks for editing your older question, but there's really no point to reopen it if it's already answered in a duplicate. It'd make a difference if your question had no answers or there wasn't a duplicate already.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on how you format the disk.

- [Amiga rigid disk block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_Disk_Block): Linked list of partitions. Thus you can keep adding until the disk is full with partition entries (and no data). For practical use: unlimited partitions.
- Ancient MBR: 4  (4 primary partitions)
- MBR with extended partitions: 3 primary, one extended which is a linked list (and thus infinite?).
- GPT: 128
- BSD [Disklabel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_disklabel): 15 or more.
- Apple partition map: ...

Etc etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can create 4 primary partitions, but any number of extended partition.

See the difference at:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning#Primary_partition

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows and GPT partitioning you can have maximum 128 partitions on hardisk, although GPT itself doesn't limit the number of partitions (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463525.aspx).

If you are using MBR you can have 4 primary partitions or 3 primary and one extended partition which can then have multiple logical drives, as far as I can tell by searching online there is no definite limit to the number of logical partitions. In this [thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproinstall/thread/c6e44245-35a6-4afa-a3b4-941a559b2334) you can see a guy did the test and gave up at 347 logical partitions