# How do I create partitions on my Lenovo U310 laptop?

Tags: windows, windows-7, ubuntu-12.04

I have four partitions (windows allows four only), by default on my laptop.

1. System -- from where the windows boots.
2. C:\ -- where the windows is located and all my stuff on computer
3. D:\ -- the backups of drivers etc are located
4. Hidden -- where the backup of windows is located (I guess)

So if I need to install Ubuntu, how do I create partitions on this? As my wubi Install is not working coolly (installed many times, randomly shows a GRUB shell error on starting). I was planning to make a windows, an Ubuntu and a shared partition. The image to the windows disk managment can be accessed at https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkYXk.jpg

Answer (score 1):

A drive can only have 4 partitions.
Primary, that is. ([see this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/368173/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-partitions-that-can-be-made-on-a-hard-drive))

So space is just one concern. (You would have to shrink the big part, and then move left the others. Which mean moving all the data to the left.)

Theory aside, you still have 4 partitions.
I would simply save down the recovery partition (with CloneZilla for example), delete it, and create an extended partition with Ubuntu or whatever Linux distro you want. You can compress the saved file/image with 7z or some other ultra-compressing archiver. Well, I would do the same with the "Lenovo" partition as well. But the choice is clearly up to you.

Comment: An *MBR formatted* drive can only have 4 partitions.