# Install windows on unallocated space (without formatting rest of partitions)

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning, windows-installation

Situation:

I had 2hdd, one was used for OS, the other was just storage divided in several partition. OS hdd was removed, so now I have pc without OS and data that I do not want to loose.

Fortunately, I have around ~60GB of free space, where, I thought, i could straight away install new windows.

However, when I need to choose partition to install Windows on (there are 3, but same HDD), it does not allow me to do anything - 
***"..windows cannot be installed partition contains one or more dynamic volumes.."***

I don't want to loose my data. Is there a way to make this work and use that unallocated space for OS?

EDIT: i figured out that I need to change partition from dynamic to basic, without loosing data via command line during boot. Is it possible?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you have MBR partitions if thats the case you can't have more then 3 physical partitions.

Comment: @Ramhound :- Didn't you mean he can't have more than [4](http://superuser.com/questions/368173/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-partitions-that-can-be-made-on-a-hard-drive) physical partitions?

Comment: See if this helps :- http://www.partitionwizard.com/dynamicdisk/how-to-change-my-pc-drive-dynamic-to-primary.html

Comment: @Firelord thats what i want to do, but, i cannot boot and use software. I have laptop with this HDD without os. Is there I way i could do this via command line?

Comment: Is it possible to change from dynamic to basic (partition) without loosing data via command line during boot ?

Comment: Even if it's possible, as with every operation of this nature it is very highly recommended that you have an up to date backup of all your important data.

Comment: One way would be to get an OS (linux) on a USB drive. Then backup the data. Then you could reconfigure the drive and put your OS of choice one it.